# SDL 2.0 - Mouse movements are spaming event queue

Tags: events, queue, mouse, sdl, sdl-2

As tittle says, mouse movements are spaming event queue so i can't for example walk when i shake my mouse around. Is there any way ? Diffrent queue for mouse only or something.

```
SDL_Event event_;
    CInputManager::Instance()->SetEvent(&event_);
    InitializeGameFiles();
    while (running)
    {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event_))
        {
            if (event_.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                running = false;
            }
            else if (event_.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
            {
                CCrosshair::Instance()->OnUpdate();
            }
        }
        OnUpdate(SDL_GetTicks() - currentTime);
        currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
        OnRender();
    }

void OnUpdate(unsigned int deltaTime)
{
    //Game logic here
    CInputManager* IM = CInputManager::Instance();
    CPlayer* player = &CPlayer::PlayerControl;
    IM->UpdateHeyHeld();
    if (IM->IsKeyDown(SDLK_w))
    {
        cam[1] += speed * (deltaTime / 1000.f ); 
    }
    else if (IM->IsKeyDown(SDLK_s))
    {
        cam[1] -= speed * (deltaTime / 1000.f ); 
    }

    if (IM->IsKeyDown(SDLK_a))
    {
        cam[0] += speed * (deltaTime / 1000.f );
    }
    else if (IM->IsKeyDown(SDLK_d))
    {
        cam[0] -= speed * (deltaTime / 1000.f ); 
    }

    if (IM->IsKeyDown(SDLK_q))
    {
        player->OnRotate(- (int) asp * (deltaTime / 1000.f) );
    }
    if (IM->IsKeyDown(SDLK_e))
    {
        player->OnRotate((int)asp * (deltaTime / 1000.f));
    }
    if (IM->IsKeyDown(SDLK_x))
    {
        ent->animation->SetAnimation(0);
    }
    else if (IM->IsKeyDown(SDLK_c))
    {
        ent->animation->StopAnimation();
    }

    ent->animation->OnUpdate();
}
```

The mouse/crosshair handling is not really relevant here, even without it it lags

Comment: Show us how you handle events, we can't help you unless you post some code.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is here :

```
if (SDL_PollEvent(&event_)) // <--- Change if to while
{
    if (event_.type == SDL_QUIT)
    {
        running = false;
    }
    else if (event_.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
    {
        CCrosshair::Instance()->OnUpdate();
    }
}
```

Running this in an `if` means you'll only take an event off the event queue per frame. SDL tends to spam mouse events even if you just move the mouse a little. And since you only take one event from the queue every frame, the number of mouse events in the queue will just keep increasing and the keydown/up events will get "lost" in the queue. far outnumbered by mouse events.

You can check out the [SDL2 wiki](http://wiki.libsdl.org/FrontPage) for more information.

Comment: if i do this, then the game updates only when queue is empty. When i add OnUpdate()/OnRender() to the loop the game freezes when there is nothing in queue.

Comment: @PatrykSeregiet Looping through all the events shouldn't take a lot of time. My suggestion is that you change the input manager so that it keeps track of all keys, mouse position, etc... The input manager itself can run the event loop, this makes everything quicker and easier

Comment: @PatrykSeregiet Disregard what I said. I'm not entirely sure how your Input Manager operates. But clearly you need to change what happens in  the event loop so that it can run several times every frame without impacting the performance. Any functions that needs to be run every frame, must be placed after the event loop.

Comment: The input manager (right now) is just a table of bools that is constantly updating if the key is pressed or not.